# "Appending" instead of overriding superclass instance variables

Tags: python, subclass

Is there a way, in Python, to do something like this?

```
class A():
    var = "1, 2, 3"

class B():
    var = ... ", 4"


instance = B()
instance.var # = 1, 2, 3, 4
```

Comment: When you tried `var = A.var + ", 4"`, what happened?

Comment: Oh, man. That was easy! Please answer the question. I will check as the accepted answer. Does `A.var` mean "get var from superclass" in that case?

Comment: No, it means "get `var` from `A`". Of course in this specific case `A` is the super class.

Comment: @delnan: um, no -- `B` only has `object` for a superclass.

Comment: Question title bears no resemblance to the provided code. A is not a superclass in this case; there's no relationship between A and B. I fear OP is confused about class vs instance variables as well as the relationship between lists and strings.

Comment: @EthanFurman: Yes, you're right, I completely missed that B doesn't actually inherit from `A` since OP was talking about superclasses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example given in the question uses neither a superclass nor an instance variable. From the title of the question, presumably you wanted to use both. Here's an example of how it would work:

```
class A(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.var = "1,2,3"

class B(A):
  def __init__(self):
    super(B,self).__init__()
    self.var += ",4,5"

print A().var
print B().var
```

Note that your example simply assigns attributes to unrelated classes, using the classes sort-of like namespaces. Which is perfectly reasonable, but not quite what you asked:

```
class A:
  var = "1,2,3"

class B:
  var = A.var + ",4,5"

print A.var
print B.var
```

Comment: This creates instance variables, which is quite different. Of course OP may actually want that and simply mistake class variables for a shortcut for defining instance variables (that happens depressingly often), but that doesn't justify your answer unless you include such an explanation. And even then it should probably be a comment like "Are you aware ...?".

Comment: The title of the question **does** say "instance variables". Have a look. It also says "superclass", which again; nothing like his example, but certainly answers the question.

Comment: @delnan, instance variables is what the OP ask for in the post title... and fails to accomplish in the code

Answer (score 1):

you can't append, you replace, but you can replace by an expression that includes the original:

```
class A(object):
    var = "1, 2, 3"

class B(A):
    var = A.var + ", 4"


instance = B()
instance.var # = 1, 2, 3, 4
```

That does it for simple uses, but a more interesting solution might be to use a descriptor;  The easy way is to use `property`

```
class A(object):
    var = "1, 2, 3"

class B(A):
    _subvar = ", 4"
    @property
    def var(self):
        return super(B, self).var + self._subvar


instance = B()
instance.var # = 1, 2, 3, 4
```

Which works for instances of `B`, but not for `B` itself (as in the first example).  To get that back, you must implement your own descriptor:

```
class Appender(object):
    def __init__(self, cls, attr):
        self.cls = cls
        self.attr = attr
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        var = super(self.cls, owner).var
        return var + getattr(self.cls, self.attr)

class B(A):
    _realvar = ', 4'
B.var = Appender(B, '_realvar')
```

Which works equally well on the class as it does on instances of the class